# Java Class Load from Linux Terminal

Tags: java, linux, load, cnf, dacapo

I am trying to load my java Harness class (DaCapo Benchmark suite) with the appropriate benchmarks java classes (cnf.files). In windows the command " java Harness  works absolutely fine. However, since I am new to Linux when I try to load my java harness class I take the message "unknown benchmark". Note that "java Harness -l" shows all the available benchmarks of this java Harness class.

Do you have any idea how can I load my java Harness class like I do in Windows?

```
  -s,--size <SIZE>                       Size of input data
    --scratch-directory <dir>           Specify an alternate scratch
                                        directory <dir>
 -t,--thread-count <thread_count>       Set the thread count to drive the
                                        workload (mutually exclusive -k)
 -v,--verbose                           Verbose output
    --validation-report <report_file>   Report digests, line counts etc
    --variance <pct>                    Target coefficient of variation
                                        <pct> (default 3.0)
    --window <window>                   Measure variance over <window>
                                        runs (default 3)
spyros@spyros-G41M-Combo:~/workspace/SpyDacaPo$ java Harness -l
/home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/HelloWorld /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/binarytrees /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/fannkuchredux /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/fastaredux /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/foo /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/mandelbrot /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/meteor /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/nbody /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/pidigits /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/regexdna /home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/revcomp
spyros@spyros-G41M-Combo:~/workspace/SpyDacaPo$ java Harness HelloWorld
Unknown benchmark: HelloWorld
spyros@spyros-G41M-Combo:~/workspace/SpyDacaPo$
```

Comment: What version are you using? 9.12-bach? And what Java version?

Answer (score 0):

you must add `HelloWorld`'s path to classpath:

```
java -cp .:/home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/ Harness HelloWorld
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. My echo$classpath is empty. I have not enter the class files in eclpise but I am sure that I can load the main Harness class from outside.

Comment: spyros@spyros-G41M-Combo:~/workspace/SpyDacaPo$ java -cp .:/home/spyros/workspace/SpyDacaPo/cnf/ Harness HelloWorld
Unknown benchmark: HelloWorld
spyros@spyros-G41M-Combo:~/workspace/SpyDacaPo$